# Invalid image on Creating thumbnails from video with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, video-thumbnails

Trying to generate an Thumbnail image from video , the file is created but , errors as Invalid image on load .Using this package [video_thumbnail](https://pub.dev/packages/video_thumbnail)

Creating thumbnail ,

```
Future<File> genThumbnail(url) async {
    //WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    Uint8List bytes;
    final Completer<ThumbnailResult> completer = Completer();
      bytes = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailData(
          video: url,
          imageFormat: ImageFormat.JPEG,
          maxHeight: 250,
          maxWidth: 300,
          timeMs: 0,
          quality: 0);

    int _imageDataSize = bytes.length;
    print("image size: $_imageDataSize");

    //final _image = Image.memory(bytes);
    //var _file =File.fromRawPath(bytes);

    Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    var uint8list = bytes;
    var buffer = uint8list.buffer;
    ByteData byteData = ByteData.view(buffer);
    File file = await File('${tempDir.path}/img/THUMBNAIL${DateTime.now().toIso8601String()}.JPEG').writeAsBytes(
        buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));

    return file;
  }
```

Saving to firestore

```
await genThumbnail(fileurl).then((_thumbFIle) async{
          String Thumbfileurl = await uploadFile(_thumbFIle, 'thumbnailOf${filenamewithoutExtension}.JPEG', 'videothumbnail');
          await sendFileToFirestoreChat(fileType, fileurl, filenamewithoutExtension,Thumbfileurl);
          return fileurl;
        });
```

The Saved Image ,
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/proj-inhouse.appspot.com/o/videos%2Fvideothumbnails%2FthumbnailOfVID-20210301-WA0006.JPEG?alt=media&token=fa4f23c1-601f-486b-97d1-c63e221166af

Comment: what is `buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes)` for? why dont you simply use `Uint8List bytes`?

Comment: @pskink same Invalid image , tried File file = await File('${tempDir.path}/img/THUMBNAIL${DateTime.now().toIso8601String()}.JPEG').writeAsBytes(buffer.asUint8List());

Comment: what do you see if you call: `bytes.take(16).map((i) => i.toRadixString(16)).forEach(print);`? does it start with `FF D8 FF DB` or `FF D8 FF E0` or `FF D8 FF EE` or `FF D8 FF E1` or something completely else? more signatures here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Comment: @pskink
I/flutter (21260): ff
I/flutter (21260): d8
I/flutter (21260): ff
I/flutter (21260): e0
I/flutter (21260): 0
I/flutter (21260): 10
I/flutter (21260): 4a
I/flutter (21260): 46
I/flutter (21260): 49
I/flutter (21260): 46
I/flutter (21260): 0
I/flutter (21260): 1
I/flutter (21260): 1
I/flutter (21260): 0
I/flutter (21260): 0
I/flutter (21260): 1

Comment: @pskink it is JPEG signature right , does the case make any difference ?

Comment: seems it is `FF D8 FF E0 00 10 4A 46 49 46 00 01` (JPEG raw or in the JFIF or Exif file format) - now try to check if uploaded image starts with the same data

Comment: also instead of `writeAsBytes(buffer.asUint8List())` simply use `writeAsBytes(bytes)` - no need for any `buffer`

Comment: @pskink that worked ,writeAsBytes(bytes) , the image is distorted though , I will have to work on that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this as a Community Wiki as it's based on @pskink comments.

To resolve, add the `writeAsBytes(bytes)` instead of `writeAsBytes(buffer.asUint8List())`. There is no need for any `buffer`.